# Create for each Array content a new Variable in Actionscript

Tags: arrays, variables, actionscript

It's me again and I'm really having troubles with that simple thing -.-

I have an array with 5 numbers in it and I want for each number to create an own variable

For instance:

```
Array [4, 12, 52, 23, 55]. create:
Variable1 = 4;
Variable2 = 4;
```

Now, I know that I can do that with a For Loop but however I simply dont know how to attach a NUMBER to the variable's name which I'm defining. I have something like this already:

```
                    var number:int=0;

                for (var bla in xvalue) {
                    var endxvalue+nummer:int = +xvalue[bla];
                    number++;
                }
```

So that I get the varibables endxvalue1 = ..; endxvalue2= ...; etc. but i cannot get the numbers after the variables name (endvalue**1**, endvalue**2**, etc) handled.

How can I achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, dynamic names for local variables are not allowed. But! You can use Object as a collection to handle your task.

```
var xvalue:Array = [4, 12, 52, 23, 55]; 

var endvalues:Object = new Object();
for each (var i:int in xvalue)
{
    endvalues['endxvalue' + i] = i;
}

trace(endvalues.endxvalue4); //traces "4"
```

Comment: If the base type of OP's class is `MovieClip`, then it's dynamic and he will succeed. Otherwise yes.

Comment: I think that it is not necessary to extend MovieClip with my solution, on the other hand your solution works only if the class is declared as dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer: use `this[]` with a string expression in brackets to create a custom property.

```
for (k in yourArray) {
    v=yourArray[k];
    this['Variable'+k]=v;
}
```

But, it'll be WAY better to use the array as it is, addressing as `this.yourArray[index]`.